# Rails 3.x asset pipeline including coffeescript file in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I have recently came across where I would like to simply just include a coffeescript file in a single Rails view, but when you use the `javascript_include_tag` it appends `.js` to the end of the name you pass in (for obvious reasons).

Has anyone come up with a solution to simply just include a coffeescript file on a page without this happening?

Comment: Are you sure you want `<script src="stuff.coffee">` in your page? The browser won't know what to do with that.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, its just cause I am not wanting some coffeescript files to be loaded on every page. It basically boils down to a script I am working on needs to be converted to a jQuery plugin, but haven't had the opportunity to do it, so I have some duplicated efforts and its causing issues on a couple of pages... bad programming, I know :(

Answer (score 0):

i did this to load only the relevant JS for each controller:
in `application.html.erb` where you see

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

please add

`<%= javascript_include_tag controller_path, :media => "all" %>`

also remove the
`#=import .`
from application.js

this way only the `myController.coffee.js` is loaded from `myController` this way you can have a more granular control of the loaded js and you can use `application.js` for common code

it's not the best solution in terms of user download but if you don't care about a few more connections I find this easier to understand (same thing can be done with css)